# Передача $id при помощи AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Как передать переменную $id используя такую структуру?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#myForm').submit(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "system/edit_record.php",
                    data: {
                            'title' : $("#title").val(),
                            'record' : $("#record").val()
                        },
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#info").html(html);
                   }
                });

                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Простите, а где здесь переменная $id? Или вы имеете ввиду php-переменную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли понял автора, но если требуется из php передать в js переменную, то самый простой способ вот (только для чисел):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var id = <?php echo $id ?>;

        $('#myForm').submit(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "system/edit_record.php",
                data: {
                        'id' : id,
                        'title' : $("#title").val(),
                        'record' : $("#record").val()
                    },
                success: function(html){
                    $("#info").html(html);
               }
            });

            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Да, но этот id ещё нужно передать файлу edit_record.php

Comment: Ну это ведь уже просто, отредактировал код

Comment: В том и проблема, что id не передаётся....

Comment: Посмотрите выше, обратите внимание на строку:

    var id = <?php echo $id ?>;

Comment: Это я уже туплю, в файле обработчика вместо $_POST['id'] написал просто $id. Спасибо, очень помогли!

Comment: Корректно будет отметить ответ "решением" и другие пользователи будут видеть, что вы получили ответ на свой вопрос)